# How do you create a telescoping set of terms in python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to animate a line moving through a maze and was wondering if there was a way to easily make a telescoping list.

For instance, `bfs(grid)` returns a list of coordinate pairs, e.g.

```py
[(0,1),(0,2),(0,3)....]
```

and I was wondering if there was a way to take that list and return

```py
[[(0,1)] , [(0,1), (0,2)] , [(0,1) , (0,2), (0,3)]]
```

Answer (score 2):

With recent (> 3.8) versions of Python you make good use of the [walrus operator](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions) for this:

```
l = [(0,1),(0,2),(0,3)]
x = []

[x := x + [t] for t in l]
# [[(0, 1)], [(0, 1), (0, 2)], [(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3)]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use list slicing with a list comprehension:

```py
[lst[:idx + 1] for idx in range(len(lst))]
```

This outputs:

```py
[[(0, 1)], [(0, 1), (0, 2)], [(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3)]]
```